# Join a table that right table is a concatenated name from column value from left table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a schema that create other tables dynamically and register the table id like this:

```
table a:
userId, fisrtsname, lastname, tableId (tableId inserted dynamically ) 
1,      john,       lenon,    1001

table b_1001 (created dynamically) (1001 was wrote on table a dynamically)
userId, adress, city
1, 15yh avenue, london
```

I need to join these tables based on table_id from first table.

Is it possible?

I tried this:

```
SELECT a.*, CONCAT('b_', a.tableId) tbl_b
FROM a
LEFT JOIN tbl_b b ON a.userId = b.userId
```

I want for this

```
Result: firstname, lastname, address, city
```

Comment: You have to use prepared statement for that, raw query can't do that. You can write a procedure to do the same.

Comment: It's **dynamically** - not "dinamcally" .....